# How to install apt-get for Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, installation, apt-get

I'm trying to use apt-get on AWS EC2 with Ubuntu 10.04, but got the following error.

sudo: apt-get: command not found

So I'll have to install apt-get. Is there a tutorial for that? I did some search online, but only finds installation guide for other Linux releases. Thanks.

Comment: Amazon linux uses yum instead of apt-get.

Answer (score -4):

I think you are using the command incorrectly! apt-get is built in with every release of Ubuntu. If for example you want to install vim you would type

sudo apt-get install vim

To check the documentation of apt-get type:

man apt-get

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm quite sure apt-get is missing. Typed the command you posted and got the same error. apt-get should be built in Ubuntu, but it's somehow missing in AWS EC2.

Comment: A possibly very stupid question: are you typing the command in terminal? 

Applications->Accessories->Terminal

Sorry for the stupid question but don't want to scream Tv malfunction with the power cord not connected!

Comment: Yes in terminal ssh-ed to Ubuntu, and typed it in Ubuntu.